# Why isn't crontab running every minute

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I have a cron that needs to run every minute

I tried

```
1 * * * * php /scripts/cron.php
```

but seems not to run every minute, why? Since in the minute tab I entered 1 for every minute

but the following runs every minute

```
* * * * * php /scripts/cron.php
```

Comment: next time read the man or one of the numerous questions asked here in the same topic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1 in the first column doesn't mean "every minute", it means "one minute past the hour".

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand, sorry new to crons

Answer (score 5):

"every minute" has to be entered like this:

`*/1 * * * * php /scripts/cron.php`

Comment: You don't need the `/1`.

Comment: But it won't throw any errors, right?

Comment: I prefer the /1, it's more explicit.

Comment: So shouldn't that be `*/1 */1 */1 */1 */1` for consistency?

Comment: Not necessarily, that's too much :) Rhe guy is new to crontab and I just wanted to show him how the right syntax for "every something" looks like. There was no need to hit negative rating since there was nothing wrong with the instructions. Difference between personal preferences doesn't mean that one solution is wrong or superior in any way than another ;)

Answer (score 1):

The column is the minutes in the hour to run the command, not how often to run

You could go with

1,2,3,4, all the way up to 59 * * * * php /scripts/cron.php if you were bored and wanted to list out every minute manually, or you could just do what you've actually done, the * means "run every time".

Ewan

Answer (score 1):

Nice explanation is on wikipedia.org:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Operators