# 5 Asterisks in crontab entry

Tags: cron

If there is an entry in crontab with the following syntax:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/program
```

How often would this be run? How would it initially get launched?

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/q/79537/9278

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cron entry will execute every single minute of every hour of every single day of every single month of every single year

Answer (score -1):

A search for crontab syntax will give you man indepth explanations.

I find it handy to note the ordering in a comment at the top as a reminder.

Comment: Or you can just do `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: @Dennis, do you really think most of us would remember what number to use in a man command? If we could remember that much we probably wouldn't need to keep using man.

Comment: @John: `man crontab`, scroll to the bottom, see See Also "crontab(5)", `man man` the sections are listed on the second (25-line) screenful. "5   File formats and conventions". My comment was not intended as an "oh should already know this", but as "here's some useful information".

Comment: @Dennis, I've never noticed that in a man file, probably because I only look for specific information. I'll try to keep it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Just `man crontab` will do. The crontab manpage is not always in section 5. I'm typing this from Slackware Linux 13.1 and it's in section 1 here.